# Is there a sympy function to extract coefficients of negative power monomials?

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials, coefficients

I have a polynomial: eps * x<sup>3</sup> - x<sup>2</sup> + 2 + 3 * x * eps<sup>-2</sup>.
How can I get a list of all coefficients including negative?

I have tried `coeffs()` and `all_coeffs()` methods but they do not work with negative powers of epsilon:

```py
import sympy as sp
x, eps = sp.symbols('x E')
expr = eps * x**3 - x**2 + 2 + 3 * x * eps**(-2)
coeffs_list = sp.Poly(expr, eps).coeffs()
```

I want to get list of coefficients like `[x^3, x^2 + 2, 3*x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying with a large power of eps helps to get the coeffients.

```py
import sympy as sp
x, eps = sp.symbols('x E')
expr = eps * x**3 - x**2 + 2 + 3 * x * eps**(-2)
coeffs_list = sp.Poly(expr*eps**2, eps).coeffs()
```

gives

```
[x**3, 2 - x**2, 3*x]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure what the negative power of `eps` is you can find the coefficients of the expression when put over a common denominator:

```
>>> n, d  expr.as_numer_denom()
>>> Poly(n, eps).coeffs()
[x**3, 2 - x**2, 3*x]
```